# Custom input view does not work anymore in the iPhone iOS 6 simulator

Tags: view, input, uitextfield, ios6, customization

I have made an app, which has a custom input view, it works fine on the ios 4.3.3 and ios 5.1.1 as well as the new ios 6 if compiled using xcode 4.3 with the base SDK 4 but after updating xcode to the latest version and compiling using the ios 6 sdk the input view does not work anymore. if input button are taped the text doesn't show in the textField. Does anyone encounter this  problem or now its cause ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are initializing your custom input view with a frame that has a width or height larger than zero.  From what I can tell, if this isn't the case then iOS 6 doesn't even add the view to the view hierarchy.

In my case, the width of my keyboard view's frame was zero when calling initWithFrame:(CGRect).  Everything worked fine in iOS 5, as the frame width would get set during layout, but in iOS 6 the keyboard wasn't even in the view hierarchy.

I used [iOS Hierarchy Viewer](https://github.com/glock45/iOS-Hierarchy-Viewer) to figure that last bit out with having to fiddle in the debugger too much.